# Gensim doc2vec training stalled

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I have been training a gensim doc2vec model for a couple days on 10 epochs. It's been running smoothly until it got to 79.29% on the last Epoch, and it suddenly stopped logging anything new. The last message logged was:

> INFO:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH 10 - PROGRESS: at 79.29% examples, 8566 words/s, in_qsize 0, out_qsize 0

There is a line of code that saves the model after the 10 epochs, but it hasn't saved anything. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Does the machine still show as busily executing one or more Python threads? Is there any other output at any console or log? Is it running in a form (interpreter or Jupyter notebook) where you could plausibly interrupt the last cell/script you executed (via a menu option or CTRL-C) and get back a stack of where it was interrupted? Is there any hint of files appearing at the location the save was intended? (It's highly likely the attempted-save is implicated: normal training that succeeds for more than 1 epoch would normally continue to the end without challenges.)

Comment: Can you show the code that's trying to save the model? Are you sure you need to do such a save-after-epochs rather than just one save at the very end? Could you test your saving code (and full pipeline) with a tiny dummy corpus – for example, just the 1st 1000 documents – to make sure all steps run to completion quickly in that reduced case?

Comment: Finally, that rate (`8566 words/s`) is quite slow. Are all the progress log lines showing a similar rate? Are you sure the optimized cython code is being used? (If not there should have been a logged warning or two earlier in your output, and training will be 100x or more slower, and fixing that would be the topmost priority.) Is there anything else custom/extreme about your chosen training parameters or data/preprocessing that might account for very-slow training?

Comment: The save code does run at the very end, after all 10 epochs have run. It is a simple one that uses pickle to convert it to a bytes object and saves to s3.

It's running on Amazon ECS and it does indicate that Python is still running, but there is nothing being output to the log.

That rate seems to be constant throughout training. I'm not sure if the cython code was being used, but it did not receive any warnings. It is just training on CPU, no GPUs, if that helps.

Comment: Running `gensim.models.doc2vec.FAST_VERSION` returns 1, so I think it's using the cython code.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ECS, but on a normal Linux/UNIX machine there'd be a way to monitor if the processes are still keeping CPUs busy – such as via the `top` command – and that's what should be checked. Is it running in a form (interpreter or Jupyter notebook) where you could plausibly interrupt the last cell/script you executed (via a menu option or CTRL-C) and get back a stack of where it was interrupted? (If not, how is it launched & how are you viewing its output?)

Comment: Is still likely the saving code is implicated in the problem. Normally, if you let the training finish and then ran code-to-save, there'd be a bunch of additional INFO-logged lines – which is why it sounded like you were trying to save in some other per-epoch handler (which is probably a bad idea in your situatiion). Can you show the code you're using the train & save the model? Is there anything else custom/extreme about your chosen training parameters or data/preprocessing that might account for very-slow training?

Comment: Also, note that plain Python pickle has problems with larger models; the `gensim` built-in `.save()` will be more effective (though will also tend to split larger models among multiple files). How large is your corpus and model, in terms of the number-of-unique words & number-of-unique tags reported early in the logging? Could you test your saving code (and full pipeline) with a tiny dummy corpus – for example, just the 1st 1000 documents – to make sure all steps run to completion quickly in that reduced case?